# Check if one of the values contain line breaks

Tags: kotlin

i am new to Kotlin

I would like to iterate through my map and check if there is line break anywhere  and if so return false, what would be the best approach. I am not sure if i can use mathches , but yeh basically if. lets say there is a string value "Hello" +c /n + "world": i would like to return false

```
 fun isLineBreakExist(languageMap: MultiLanguageString){
    languageMap.forEach { (value) -> value.matches("")   }

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `MultiLanguageString`? Is `value` every element or key in `MultiLanguageString`?

Comment: Not knowing what `MultiLanguageString` is, perhaps `return !languageMap.any {value -> value.contains("LINE BREAK"}

Comment: @Gavin is just a collection  but yes i think you right alli need to do is the following :
fun isLineBreakExist(languageMap: MultiLanguageString): Boolean {
               !languageMap.any {value -> value.contains("[/r/n]"}
           }}

Comment: @ChristianB the actual collection